# $V:= \{ A \in M_2(\mathbb{C}): A^*=A\} $ is a vector space over $\mathbb {R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V:= \{ A \in M_2(\mathbb{C}): A^*=A\} $ is a vector space over $\mathbb {R}$

$(a)$ Find $V$ dimension over $\mathbb {R}$

$(b)$ Define $q:V \to \mathbb {R} , q(A)=2\cdot det(A)$, prove $q$ is a quadratic form

$(d)$ Find rank and signature of $q$

My solution :

$(a)$ The basis $B:=\bigg \{ \left ( \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ), \left ( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ),\left ( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right )\bigg\},\left ( \begin{matrix}
    0 & i \\
    -i & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right )\bigg\}$

Then , $dimV=4$

$(b)$ How am I supposed to prove that $q$ is a quadratic form.

I saw this post [Quadratic form on the space of Hermitian matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2369888/quadratic-form-on-the-space-of-hermitian-matrices) But I still don't get how to prove it and how get the representation matrix.

Please help

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\det \left[x_1 \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} + x_2 \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} + x_3 \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} + x_4\pmatrix{0&i\\-i & 0} \right] =\\
x_1x_2 - (x_3 + x_4i)(x_3 - x_4i) = \\
x_1x_2 - x_3^2 - x_4^2.
$$

Comment: $q(A)=x_1x_2-x_3^2-x_4^2$ maybe I can show $f(X,Y)=x_1y_2-x_3y_3-x_4y_4$ is a bilinear form ?

Comment: @erez You could take an approach along those lines. However, you should instead consider the symmetric bilinear form 
$$
f(X,Y) = \frac 12 x_1y_2 + \frac 12 x_2y_1 - x_3y_3 - x_4y_4.
$$

Comment: Is it enough to show that $f(X,Y) = \frac 12 x_1y_2 + \frac 12 x_2y_1 - x_3y_3 - x_4y_4$ is a bilinear form?

Comment: @erez For part (b), yes